# Calculating confusion matrix for fixed effect logit

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression, confusion-matrix

I would like to ask how to calculate a confusion matrix for a fixed effect logit model (`bife` package)

With the basic logit model (`glm`) there is no problem, but with fixed effect logit there is.

For some reason the number of predictions is different for logit and fixed effect logit.

Example:

```
library(bife)
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)

dataset <- psid

logit <- glm(LFP ~ AGE + I(AGE^2) + log(INCH) + KID1 + KID2 + KID3, data = dataset, family = "binomial")
mod <- bife(LFP ~AGE +  I(AGE^2) + log(INCH) + KID1 + KID2 + KID3| ID, dataset)

summary(mod)
summary(logit)

predict(logit)
predict(mod)

Y <- factor(dataset$LFP)
PRE <- factor(round(predict(logit, type = "response")))
PRE_FIX <- factor(round(predict(mod, type = "response")))

confusionMatrix(Y, PRE)

# Not working
confusionMatrix(Y, PRE_FIX)
```

Comment: The help page for bife says it "drops all observations of cross-sectional units (individuals) with non-varying response."

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to compute the `confusionMatrix`:

```
confusionMatrix<-table(true=Y , pred = round(fitted(PRE_FIX)))
```

And then, convert the confusion matrix to a table shape.

```
  0             1
0 TruePositive  FalseNegative
1 FalsePositive TrueNegative
```

Comment: You should explain how the code works, even if only briefly. Posts of code without explanations are frowned upon :)